# Mark row as selected after closing modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table, with many rows. From each row it is possible to open modal dialog with code (click on the first cell of the row), what I do with this code:

```
var SetInventoryForAllCalendarsAndGroups = function () {

  var OpenModalGroup = function (element) {
          $("#myModalJEINVE_Group").modal();
  }


  return {
    OpenModalGroup: OpenModalGroup
  }      

  }();
```

What I don't know is how to select row after modal dialog is closed (same row where modal was opened from)? So the row acts like it was clicked before opening modal dialog (in my case it's marked with yellow color).

Example is [here](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/xXammG/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

`$(element).paremts('tr').addClass('active')`

**JS**

```
var SetInventoryForAllCalendarsAndGroups = function () {

  var OpenModalGroup = function (element) {
          $(element).parents('tr').addClass('active'); // here it is
          $("#myModalJEINVE_Group").modal();
  }


  return {
    OpenModalGroup: OpenModalGroup
  }      

  }();
```

**CSS**

```
.table tbody tr.active td {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```